# Android http download at very very low priority

Tags: android, http, download, android-volley, okhttp

My Android app needs to do a large (~150MB) download in the background. I am using an intent service and doing this in the background.

The problem is that this big download cloggs all other downloads.

(I'm using Volley+Glide for image downloads in the app and OkHTTP for the large file download. I would use Volley for everything, but since it's not recommended for large files, I'm using okHttp.)

Volley has a way of setting download priorities, but AFAIK, that's only used to determine WHEN a download starts, not for the % of bandwidth a d/l uses.

I was not able to find a way to set okHTTP to download at a very low priority.

Ideally, what I would like to do is just set the large okHttp download to a very low priority, and it would let everything else download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class called `ThrottledSource` that extends Okio’s [ForwardingSource](https://square.github.io/okio/okio/ForwardingSource.html). This class needs to limit the kilobytes per second. You can see examples of throttling a stream in [MockWebServer.java](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/mockwebserver/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/mockwebserver/MockWebServer.java).

When you're done you'll have a stream that downloads slower than it needs to. That'll free up bandwidth for other transfers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the file into smaller chunks, eg. split zips
2. Download the files with the IntentService when the app is not running (use JobScheduler)

Comment: While these are useful comments, I'd classify them as workarounds, not as solutions to my issue.